# AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime' even after using import datetime

Tags: python, datetime, flask

I had the following codes in my flask project that modifies the timestamp. I haven't modified anything, but the codes now throw the above mentioned error.

I have referred all the similar questions on StackOverflow but all suggests that it's due to using `from datetime import datetime` instead of `import datetime`. But in my following code, I am using `import datetime`. Yet, still I get `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`.

**My code:**

**view.py**

```py
import datetime


@app.template_filter('datetimeformat')
def datetimeformat(value, format):
    d_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return d_obj.strftime(format)

@app.template_filter('timestampformat')
def timestampformat(value, format):
    d_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # This is where the error occurs.
    current_date = datetime.date.today()
    timestamp_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date()
    if timestamp_date == current_date:
        timestamp_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').time()
        delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=5, minutes=30)
        timestamp_local = ((datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date(1,1,1),timestamp_time) + delta).time())
        return "Today at {}".format(timestamp_local.strftime('%I:%M %p'))
    else:
        return d_obj.strftime(format)
```

**template.html** `(registration['timestamp']` = `2019-09-13 13:29:47`)

```html
...
        <td>{{ registration['timestamp'] }}</td>
        {% if 'Today' in registration['timestamp']|timestampformat('%B %d, %Y %A \n %I:%M %p') %}
            <td><span class="timestamp today">{{ registration['timestamp']|timestampformat('%B %d, %Y, %A, %I:%M %p') }}</span></td>
        {% else %}
            <td><span class="timestamp">{{ registration['timestamp']|timestampformat('%B %d, %Y, %A, %I:%M %p') }}</span></td>
        {% endif %}

...
```

I am really confused what went wrong.

Comment: Can I ask, what version of python are you running?

Comment: Is it possible that you have a `datetime.py` in your working directory?

Comment: @adrianp, no I don't have any. I checked.

Comment: @Tylerr, It's python 2.7.

Comment: What happens if you run `from datetime import datetime` from a python console?

Comment: Ah i think I see whats happening here, refer to my answer.

Comment: @Tylerr, tried doing it. No errors. The import works fine. Tried both. Both work fine.

Comment: @Tylerr, I have to clarify that I deleted my previous comment because I forgot to invoke the python interpreter from the terminal. That is why I had to delete it and add a new comment, where the imports succeeded.

Comment: Ah, I'll delete my answer then haha

Comment: Is there a chance that the actual module itself is corrupt?, try reinstalling python and see if that helps.

Comment: From the error message, it seems like the `datetime` attribute is accessed twice from the module, i.e., `datetime.datetime.datetime` is being called. Import problems?

Comment: @adrianp, I searched the whole project for any lines that has `datetime.datetime.datetime`. Also, the only import statement I can find is `import datetime`. @Tylerr, I re-installed my venv and rebooted server. Still same.

Comment: Okay I think I know what's happening. Check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

From the python documentation, modules are only loaded once per session for efficiency reasons. A simple restart of your interpreter (or in this case, server) should solve the problem.

Comment: I rebooted the server. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: is this what you use `from datetime import datetime`?